# Thymeleaf URL Syntax is is confusing

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So I'm trying to generate (dynamic) links through Thymeleaf.

Now the first url I want to link to is /resource/id so I have the following:

```
<a th:href="|/resource/${resource.id}|" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit...</a>
```

Which works great, and does exactly what you would expect.

So the next url I want to link to is /resource/id/child/id so I try the following:

```
<a th:href="|/resource/${resource.id}/child/${child.id}|" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit...</a>
```

Which I thought would give me what I wanted. Instead I get:

```
/resource/3/child%7D?id=4
```

Which is weird and confusing. I'm not really sure why this happens or how to get what I want which is:

```
/resource/3/child/4
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm using spring-boot/spring-mvc if it makes any difference.

**Update**:
Okay, so after re-reading (and comprehending) the documentation, it turns out the the more correct syntax is:

```
<a th:href="@{/resource/{rid}/child/{cid}(rid=${resource.id} cid=${child.id})}" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit...</a>
```

Now I get the url:

```
/resource/3/child?id=4
```

Which while very close is still slightly wrong and confusing.

Does Thymeleaf not support more than one path variable?

Answer (score 2):

I think a comma is missing. Try like this :

```
th:href="@{/resource/{rid}/child/{cid}(rid=${resource.id},cid=${child.id})}"
```

Each key/value should be separate with a comma in order to correctly build an URL with multiple path variables.

Answer (score 0):

When working with urls you should better use the url syntax @{...} instead of literal substitution.
For example in your case:

```
    <a th:href="@{/resource/{resource.id}/child/{child.id}}" 
          href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit...</a>
```

(note the absence of the dollar sign in rest resource placeholders)

Comment: I tried this originally, but that just gives me a URL that says /resource/%7Bresource,id%7D, and the second url is /resource/%7Bresource.id%7D/child?id=4, which is even more wrong. :(

Comment: see answer by heRoy. I forgot about the parameters mapping

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the value of child.id? I used it very often like `@{|/resource/${resource.id}/child/${child.id}|}`. 
You can evaluate the syntax wit
`<a th:with="child_id='4'" th:href="@{|/resource/${resource.id}/child/${child_id}|}"`
and put a `<span th:text="${child.id}"></span>` to your html to see what value `child.id` has.